# How to make the columns in a list as long as the longest string in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a list of Names plus their main directories. How do I make it so the columns are as long as the longest string, in this case, Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor

```
names = ['Kenny Rogers', 'Reba McEntire', 'Johnny Cash', 'Tito Jackson', 'Tzuyu', 'Kareena Kapoor']
dirname = ['/home/users/krogers', '/home/rmcentire', '/home/users/jcash', '/home/hut/titoj', 
'/home/users/tzuyu', '/home/users2/kkapoor']


print("+-------+--------------------------------+")
print("|", names[0], "|", dirname[0], "    |")
print("|", names[1], "|", dirname[1], "       |")
print("|", names[2], "|", dirname[2], "       |")
print("|", names[3], "|", dirname[3], "        |")
print("|", names[4], "|", dirname[4], "             |")
print("|", names[5], "|", dirname[5], " |")
print("+-------+--------------------------------+")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data

Comment: you can use left or right justification with your strings. `str.ljust()` or `str.rjust()` are methods available for this purpose exactly. Do check my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use string left/right justification functions

Once you have calculated the max length for each of the string lists, you can use `str.ljust()` with that max length to left alight the strings. Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-ljust-rjust-center/) for more details.

```
names = ['Kenny Rogers', 'Reba McEntire', 'Johnny Cash', 'Tito Jackson', 'Tzuyu', 'Kareena Kapoor']
dirname = ['/home/users/krogers', '/home/rmcentire', '/home/users/jcash', '/home/hut/titoj', 
'/home/users/tzuyu', '/home/users2/kkapoor']

mname = max([len(i) for i in names])
mdir = max([len(i) for i in dirname])


print("+----------------+-----------------------+")
print("|", names[0].ljust(mname), "|", dirname[0].ljust(mdir), " |")
print("|", names[1].ljust(mname), "|", dirname[1].ljust(mdir), " |")
print("|", names[2].ljust(mname), "|", dirname[2].ljust(mdir), " |")
print("|", names[3].ljust(mname), "|", dirname[3].ljust(mdir), " |")
print("|", names[4].ljust(mname), "|", dirname[4].ljust(mdir), " |")
print("|", names[5].ljust(mname), "|", dirname[5].ljust(mdir), " |")
print("+----------------+-----------------------+")

+----------------+-----------------------+
| Kenny Rogers   | /home/users/krogers   |
| Reba McEntire  | /home/rmcentire       |
| Johnny Cash    | /home/users/jcash     |
| Tito Jackson   | /home/hut/titoj       |
| Tzuyu          | /home/users/tzuyu     |
| Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor  |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

---

#### For loop with zip instead of multiple prints

I would advise using a for loop with zipping instead of the multiple print statements.

```
print('+'+'-'*(mname+2)+'+'+'-'*(mdir+3)+'+')
for i,j in zip(names, dirname):
    print("|", i.ljust(mname), "|", j.ljust(mdir), " |")
print('+'+'-'*(mname+2)+'+'+'-'*(mdir+3)+'+')
```

```
+----------------+-----------------------+
| Kenny Rogers   | /home/users/krogers   |
| Reba McEntire  | /home/rmcentire       |
| Johnny Cash    | /home/users/jcash     |
| Tito Jackson   | /home/hut/titoj       |
| Tzuyu          | /home/users/tzuyu     |
| Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor  |
+----------------+-----------------------+
```

---

#### Use tabulate library

You can pip install tabulate library and use this to print out your data. It provides some interesting table formats such as `'plain'`, `'simple'`, `'grid'`, `'pipe'`, `'orgtbl'`, `'rst'`, `'mediawiki'`, `'latex'`, `'latex_raw'` and `'latex_booktabs'`. More details can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/).

```
#!pip install tabulate
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(zip(names, dirname), tablefmt="grid"))
print(tabulate(zip(names, dirname), tablefmt="orgtbl"))
print(tabulate(zip(names, dirname), tablefmt="rst"))
```

```
#grid
+----------------+----------------------+
| Kenny Rogers   | /home/users/krogers  |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Reba McEntire  | /home/rmcentire      |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Johnny Cash    | /home/users/jcash    |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Tito Jackson   | /home/hut/titoj      |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Tzuyu          | /home/users/tzuyu    |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor |
+----------------+----------------------+


#orgtbl
| Kenny Rogers   | /home/users/krogers  |
| Reba McEntire  | /home/rmcentire      |
| Johnny Cash    | /home/users/jcash    |
| Tito Jackson   | /home/hut/titoj      |
| Tzuyu          | /home/users/tzuyu    |
| Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor |


#rst
==============  ====================
Kenny Rogers    /home/users/krogers
Reba McEntire   /home/rmcentire
Johnny Cash     /home/users/jcash
Tito Jackson    /home/hut/titoj
Tzuyu           /home/users/tzuyu
Kareena Kapoor  /home/users2/kkapoor
==============  ====================
```

Comment: I would say, better than my version!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [tabulate library in Python](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) to do so.
The code for this is quite simple

```
from tabulate import tabulate

headers = ["Names", "Directories"]

names = ['Kenny Rogers', 'Reba McEntire', 'Johnny Cash', 'Tito Jackson', 'Tzuyu', 'Kareena Kapoor']

dirname = ['/home/users/krogers', '/home/rmcentire', '/home/users/jcash', '/home/hut/titoj', 
'/home/users/tzuyu', '/home/users2/kkapoor']

print(tabulate(zip(names, dirname), headers, tablefmt="grid"))
```

This is what the output looks like on execution.

```
+----------------+----------------------+
| Names          | Directories          |
+================+======================+
| Kenny Rogers   | /home/users/krogers  |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Reba McEntire  | /home/rmcentire      |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Johnny Cash    | /home/users/jcash    |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Tito Jackson   | /home/hut/titoj      |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Tzuyu          | /home/users/tzuyu    |
+----------------+----------------------+
| Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor |
+----------------+----------------------+
```

Here's a link to a live executable [Deepnote notebook](https://deepnote.com/project/3325e7a9-9f7f-469e-87d2-e8ed163a0b56) if you wish to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
names = ['Kenny Rogers', 'Reba McEntire', 'Johnny Cash', 'Tito Jackson', 'Tzuyu', 'Kareena Kapoor']
dirname = ['/home/users/krogers', '/home/rmcentire', '/home/users/jcash', '/home/hut/titoj', 
'/home/users/tzuyu', '/home/users2/kkapoor']

longest_name = max([len(i) for i in names])
longest_dirs = max([len(j) for j in dirname])


print("+"+"-"*longest_name+"+"+"-"*longest_dirs+"+")

for n, d in zip(names, dirname):
    print("|" + n + " "*(longest_name-len(n)) + "|" + d + " "*(longest_dirs-len(d)) + "|")

print("+"+"-"*longest_name+"+"+"-"*longest_dirs+"+")
```

Comment: I would say, this is better than my version!

Answer (score 1):

A generalized function using f-strings.  Use one of `<^>` for left/center/right justification:

```py
def table(*columns,justify='<'):
    widths = [max(len(n) for n in c) for c in columns]
    print('+','-+-'.join('-'*w for w in widths),'+',sep='-')
    for row in zip(*columns):
        print('|',' | '.join(f'{n:{justify}{w}}' for n,w in zip(row,widths)),'|')
    print('+','-+-'.join('-'*w for w in widths),'+',sep='-')

names = ['Kenny Rogers', 'Reba McEntire', 'Johnny Cash', 'Tito Jackson', 'Tzuyu', 'Kareena Kapoor']
dirname = ['/home/users/krogers', '/home/rmcentire', '/home/users/jcash', '/home/hut/titoj', 
'/home/users/tzuyu', '/home/users2/kkapoor']

table(names,dirname)
table(names,dirname,justify='^')
```

```
+----------------+----------------------+
| Kenny Rogers   | /home/users/krogers  |
| Reba McEntire  | /home/rmcentire      |
| Johnny Cash    | /home/users/jcash    |
| Tito Jackson   | /home/hut/titoj      |
| Tzuyu          | /home/users/tzuyu    |
| Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor |
+----------------+----------------------+
+----------------+----------------------+
|  Kenny Rogers  | /home/users/krogers  |
| Reba McEntire  |   /home/rmcentire    |
|  Johnny Cash   |  /home/users/jcash   |
|  Tito Jackson  |   /home/hut/titoj    |
|     Tzuyu      |  /home/users/tzuyu   |
| Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor |
+----------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Tabulate Module

from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(zip(names,dirname)))

Output:
--------------  --------------------
Kenny Rogers    /home/users/krogers
Reba McEntire   /home/rmcentire
Johnny Cash     /home/users/jcash
Tito Jackson    /home/hut/titoj
Tzuyu           /home/users/tzuyu
Kareena Kapoor  /home/users2/kkapoor
--------------  --------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to use any extra package, you may do it as follows:

```py
names = ['Kenny Rogers', 'Reba McEntire', 'Johnny Cash', 'Tito Jackson', 'Tzuyu', 'Kareena Kapoor']
dirname = ['/home/users/krogers', '/home/rmcentire', '/home/users/jcash', '/home/hut/titoj', 
'/home/users/tzuyu', '/home/users2/kkapoor']

mx_nm_len = max([len(x) for x in names])
mx_dirnm_len = max([len(x) for x in dirname])

print(mx_nm_len, mx_dirnm_len)

print('_'*(mx_nm_len + mx_dirnm_len + 7)) # 7 comes from the use of spaces and '|'
for n, d in zip(names, dirname):
    print('| {data1:14} | {data2:20} |'.format(data1=n, data2=d))
```

Output:

```bash
14 20
_________________________________________
| Kenny Rogers   | /home/users/krogers  |
| Reba McEntire  | /home/rmcentire      |
| Johnny Cash    | /home/users/jcash    |
| Tito Jackson   | /home/hut/titoj      |
| Tzuyu          | /home/users/tzuyu    |
| Kareena Kapoor | /home/users2/kkapoor |
```